# Remove all lines before pattern matching using sed (No remove the pattern line)

Tags: sed

I'd like to remove lines from start to the first pattern matching.(but except the pattern line)

original.txt

```
11

22
33

44

55

TEST line

66
77

TEST line2
```

expected.txt

```
TEST line

66
77

TEST line2
```

I'm using Ubuntu.
How can I do this using sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete everything that is *not* between the first occurrence of `/pattern/`, and the last line (inclusive).

```
sed '/^TEST line$/,$!d'
```

You can also use this awk, to start printing (and continue printing), when the whole line exactly matches a string:

```
awk '$0 == "TEST line" {p=1} p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
sed -n '/TEST line/,/TEST line2/p' original.txt > expected.txt

cat expected.txt
TEST line

66
77

TEST line2
```

Another potential option is to remove everything before the first pattern and everything after the second pattern (-z option requires GNU sed), e.g.

```
sed -z 's/.*\(TEST line\n\)/\1/;s/\(TEST line2\n\).*/\1/g' original.txt > expected.txt

cat expected.txt
TEST line

66
77

TEST line2
```

You can also use AWK for this type of task, e.g.

```
awk '/TEST line/,/TEST line2/' original.txt > expected.txt

cat expected.txt
TEST line

66
77

TEST line2
```

Or grep:

```
grep -A 10000 "TEST line" original.txt | grep -B 10000 "TEST line2" > expected.txt

cat expected.txt
TEST line

66
77

TEST line2
```

If you include more information in your question, such as your own attempts to solve the problem, it makes it easier to provide the most suitable answer.